# Need to quote table name after ODI migration

Tags: database, oracle, case-sensitive, quote

I was working Oracle Data Integrator 11g, and transferring tables between 2 oracle 11g2 database.
After transfer, I need to quote table name to do transactions etc.

Here is the result of :

```
SQL> select tname from tab;

TNAME
------------------------------
ogrenci2
```

Here, when i try "select * from ogrenci2" i get the "table or view does not exists" error.
When i use "select * from "ogrenci2"" it show the data. Im not very experienced in ODI or Oracle Database but my searches on google and stack didnt do anything as a solution. Btw both databases have same character sets.

Comment: And your question is?..

Comment: uhm.. yeah.. my question is why is this happening? i mean why do i have to add double quote to reach table while i can reach any other table without it. How can i fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, ODI created tables in the new database with case-sensitive names. By default most SQL databases translate object names to upper case, so for example this statement:

```
create table ogrenci2 (col1 number)
```

will create a table with the uppercase name "OGRENCI2":

```
SQL> select table_name from user_tables

TABLE_NAME
----------------------------
OGRENCI2
```

However, supplying the table name in quotes, like so:

```
create table "ogrenci2" (col1 number)
```

will create the table with the literal, lowercase name

```
SQL> select table_name from user_tables

TABLE_NAME
----------------------------
ogrenci2
```

Subsequently you will have to quote this table name each time you reference it, otherwise the database will convert it to upper case and then obviously fail to find it in the catalog.

I'm not very familiar with ODI, but there may be an option that forces uppercase object names.

Comment: Thank you very much, this information really means so much to me, to someone that is new to these oracle stuff.